# Calling nested subscribe sequentially

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

calling one subscribe which is depending one another subscribe method

structure:

```
    this.example1().subscribe(res => {
      this.response = res;
    })


  example1(): Observable<any> | any {
    this.example2().pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        return throwError(err);
      })
    ).subscribe(res => {
       return of(res);
    });
  }

  example2(): Observable<any> | any {
     this.example3().pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        return throwError(err);
      })
    ).subscribe(res => {
      return of(res);
    });

  }

  example3() {
    return of('return from example 3');
  }
```

now getting error "Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined"

example3() returns value correctly but from example2 value does not get return to example 1

link: [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eyz2j7)

Comment: `example2()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: neither does `example1()`

Comment: @denajan, when an observable depends anothe one, you must use switchMap

Comment: hi i returned value from example1() and example2().But still no luck

Answer (score 0):

`example1()` and `example2()` functions do not return anything. Just add the return keyword to return your Observables.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to subscribe in example1(), example2(), example3().
Return in async callback method **subscribe** is not return of function.

```js
  example1(): Observable<any> | any {
    console.log('1');
    return this.example2().pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        return throwError(err);
      })
    );
  }

  example2(): Observable<any> | any {
    console.log('2');
    return this.example3().pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        return throwError(err);
      })
    );
  }

  example3() {
    console.log('3');
    return of('return from example 3');
  }
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ovkz3t?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**UPDATE (15.03.2019)**
With your comment, the code should be:

```js
export class AppComponent {
  response;
  private init$: Observable<any>;

  public ngOnInit() {
    //get Data from remote
    this.example3().subscribe(value => {
      //Do primary somethimg with result
      let calcVal = value *2;
      // Do remote something with data
      this.example2(calcVal).subscribe(newValue => {
        // Result with updated data
        console.log(newValue);
        this.response = newValue;
      });
    });
  }

  // Async do something with data
  example2(value: number): Observable<string>{
    return of('Value is: ' + value);
  }

  // Async get data
  example3(): Observable<number> {
    console.log('3');
    return of(3);
  }

}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bczq5z?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Or with switchMap:

```js
export class AppComponent {
  response;
  private init$: Observable<any>;

  public ngOnInit() {
    let obs = this.example3().pipe(switchMap(val => this.example2(val)));
    obs.subscribe(result => this.response = result);
  }

  // Async do something with data
  example2(value: number): Observable<string>{
    return of('Value is: ' + value);
  }

  // Async get data
  example3(): Observable<number> {
    console.log('3');
    return of(3);
 
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aa53nn?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: thanks @lvanes for your valuable reply.It is working fine but my scenario is little bit different.I am calculating something in sample2 function where incoming value is coming from sample3() and final value will go to sample1() function.Please look at stackblitz  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eyz2j7

Comment: @debanjanMal Should your **example2** calculating been async? [Updated example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bczq5z?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: @lvanes yes it is async data but calculation part should be happen in example2() because this is common for all.I think i can use switchMap

Comment: switchMap may help you. But do you need it? It is using for combine two Observables and auto-unsubscribe if first **Observable** stream is call **next()** more than one time. Is the answer (after update) not suitable for you? ([About switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html))

Comment: @lvanes any suggestion .This is mandatory , all the calculation part will happen in example2()

Comment: If switchMap is suitable in unsubcribe (the second **next()** result of subscription **example3** restart calculation **example2**, and don't callback the first result) you may use it. If this is not your case, and you need every result of calculation use mergeMap.

Comment: Thank you so much @lvanes. I really appreciate your valuable response.I solve this problem by using swichMap.I don't know what is wrong in this question why someone dislike this question i don't know.

Comment: Not at all. You may vote on it or accept it. *Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you"*. [StackOverflow Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)